# How can i send an object to Azure in Java with Authorization key?

Tags: java, rest, azure

We built a web service in Azure. And i want to send my User object to this service. The service has an Authorization. What is the best and easy way? 
In .NET it is easy with RestClient. But in Java, don't know how it can be done.
(I am getting response from same service via URLConnection. But can't post any data.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved this problem. It can be easily done with url connection. :D